# How to check if adding child DDD entity to parent (tree-like structure) entity doesn't do cycle in another tree

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm modelling a domain where entities are packages of business services and can be made of other packages - tree structure. I have some issues with designing domain logic for avoid cycles.

Let's say we have entity (object of class "Package") PackageA and it has children (PackageB and PackageC). We also have PackageD with child PackageB. 
Now we want add PackageA to PackageB as its child - we're doing this by getting PackageB from PackageRepostiory and using PackageB::addChildPackage() method. But before that we need to make sure that adding this package won't do any loops in other trees (in the example it will). The question is how to implement this in DDD?

I thought about moving adding packages to domain service, so I can get all packages that are currently related to the package I want to modify and make a check on them if there will be no cycles.

Do you think it's good idea?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about moving adding packages to domain service, so I can get all packages that are currently related to the package I want to modify and make a check on them if there will be no cycles.
>
> Do you think it's good idea?

Yes, you can do it. Adding a `PackageServices` class that provide validation for `Package` it make some sense for your description of Domain.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate root should not contain a reference to an instance of another aggregate root.  You should indirectly reference the other aggregate using either an `Id` or a value object containing the `Id` and some extra interesting information.

Your case appears to be along the lines of a classification structure and you could event model that separately from your main aggregate.  Either way you would need to get the entire hierarchy that your aggregate belongs to an check that there is no cycle.  However, there is no guarantee that you are not creating a cycle along with another user at the same time if what you and the other user are doing would create a cycle.

More-or-less the same goes for some unique attribute such as an e-mail address.  In that case it could be as simple as creating a unique constraint on your data store.

In the case of a cyclic dependency it isn't going to be as simple as creating a constraint and the same goes for a data store that does not support unique constraints.

In such a case you would need to use a bit of a *process manager* and perform a couple of steps.  We would probably want to prevent the obvious cycles by checking for a cycle before creating the item in the hierarchy.  After you have committed your unit of work (say, transaction) you could send a message to validate the new entry.  That second step would then check for a cycle again since someone else may have created an invalid state along with you.  If you have a cycle then the last entered item "loses" and is removed an a notification of sorts published in order to make that decision known.

Another way would be to attempt to prevent creating cycles using some locking strategy.  This would have to have the correct grain depending on your design.  If you have various independent hierarchies they could be locked on a root level.  The root would be the `Package` that has no parent.  After your commit you would release the *lock*.  If you have a single hierarchy then you could probably still lock that and permit only a single change to the hierarchy at any one time.

Using a domain service for this seems to be the way to do it but that in itself does not quite solve your issue.  It is more about what that service is going to do.

Comment: I'm new in DDD - as you probably know  and your comment is priceless to me. :) About modelling classification structure separately - probably I could create a tree where value of node would be an id of agregate. I'm thinking about creating domain service where root agregates and this could "talk" to each other. @Eben Roux what do you think about this idea?

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel and probably use one of tree libs i.e. https://packagist.org/packages/nicmart/tree (I'm from PHP world :)), therefore some additional coupling between external lib and my core domain, comes into equation. Is it good idea?

Comment: Try to keep your domain free of any infrastructure.  If the referenced library is going to add significant value then try it and see how that works out.  Aggregates do interact and that typically happens using domain services and, at times, application services that perform a use case.  It is always tricky giving 100% correct advice on unknown domains but I'd suggest trying out a couple of techniques and finding that which works best.  You may even come back later and find a better solution.  As stated in the blue book you tend to go through a couple of models before finding the right fit.